# Is it possible to customize the Trace.axd page on ASP.Net?

Tags: .net, asp.net, trace

I would like to use the Trace function in asp.net, but there is a lot of information on the **Details** page that I really just don't care about. Is there a way to limit what is seen on that page?

For example, if there are a lot of controls on a page, the control tree is **ENORMOUS**. I generally don't care about controls.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

first you have to enable tracing at page level by :

```
<@Page trace="true" ... />
```

You can use the Trace class in the System.Diagnostics namespace to add your own trace messages to the data that is displayed by ASP.NET tracing.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{ 
  Trace.Write("Custom Category", "Page_Load called"); 
} 

protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{ 
  Trace.Write("Custom Category", "Button1_Click called");
```

In Trace.Write first argument is your category and second is the log message that will be displayed in trace.axd or page level.

Custom messages are embedded in the Trace Information section of the trace details

Comment: I was think more like removing the entire **Control Tree** block from the trace.axd page. Is that what you mean here?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it's possible to configure it, however, you can get the underlying data and display what you need. See my answer here on SO to this question: [Logging the data in Trace.axd to a text/xml file.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4735173/logging-the-data-in-trace-axd-to-a-text-xml-file/4826297#4826297)

Comment: All of the tables within the dataset don't have any rows in them.